# Unit group of a quotient ring $(R/I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have to show (or find a counterexample for) the following relation:

Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ an ideal of $R$ and $R/I$ the quotient ring.

If $a \in R^\times \Rightarrow a + I \in (R/I)^\times$

I have a problem in understanding how exactly the unit group $(R/I)^\times$ defined is.

The quotient ring $R/I$ is defined as follows:

Let $x,y \in R$. The the quotient ring is
$R/I := \{x + I \ | \ x \in R  \}$ with the multiplication $(x+I)(y+I) = xy + I$.

I know that the unit group of $R$ is $R^\times := \{ 
a \in R \ | \ \exists b \in R: ab = 1 \}$.

If I apply this logic to $R/I$ $\ $ I would get:

$(R/I)^\times := \{ x + I \in R/I \ | \ \exists \ y + I \in R/I : (x+I)(y+I) = 1  \}$.
But as per def. of the multiplication in $R/I$, we have $(x+I)(y+I) = xy + I$. So I don't know hot to get the $1$.

Or should it maybe be $(R/I)^\times := \{ x + I \in R/I \ | \ \exists \ y + I \in R/I : (x+I)(y+I) = 1 + I  \}$ ?

Comment: Well, $1$ denotes the identity element of the given ring, which is $1+I$ in case of $R/I$.

Comment: @Berci Thank you!

Comment: @Berci Can You maybe check if my reasoning regarding the proof for $a \in R^\times \Rightarrow a + I \in (R/I)^\times$ is correct?

Comment: @Berci Suppose $a \in R^\times$. This means that $a$ is invertible and thus $a^{-1} \in R$. Because the quotient ring is defined as $R/I := \{x + I \ | \ x \in R  \}$, we have that $a^{-1} + I \in R/I$. 

And because $(R/I)^\times := \{ x + I \in R/I \ | \ \exists \ y + I \in R/I : (x+I)(y+I) = 1  \}$ we have the case where $x = a$ and $y = a^{-1}$, so we have $(a + I) \cdot (a^{-1}+I) = aa^{-1} + I = 1 + I$. Therefore, $a+I$ is invertible and thus it follows that $a+I \in (R/I)^\times$. In the end we have: $a \in R^\times \Rightarrow a + I \in (R/I)^\times$

Comment: Yes, $a^{-1}+I$ is the inverse of $a+I$ in $R/I$.

Comment: @Berci okay thanks. And how about the other way around? So, $a \in R^\times \Leftarrow a + I \in (R/I)^\times$? Here I claim, because $ a + I \in (R/I)^\times$, there must exist an inverse element $a^{-1} + I \in (R/I)$ so that we have $(a + I)(a^{-1} + I ) = aa^{-1} + I = 1 + I$. Then it follows that because $aa^{-1} = 1$ that $a$ is invertible, i.e. $a \in R^\times$. Does this reasoning work?

Comment: No, $ab+I=1+I$ only implies $ab=1+x$ for some $x\in I$ and not $ab=1$. E.g. in $\Bbb Z/(p)$ every nonzero element is invertible but most of them were not so in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Berci okay I have to think about this a little bit. But thanks! Can you maybe give the definition of $\Bbb Z/(p)$ ? I'm not sure how it is defined

Comment: @Berci I don't understand that if $ab + I = 1 + I$ only implies $ab = 1 + x$
Edit: I noticed now that you wrote $ab = 1 + x$ and not $ab + 1 = 1+ x$ like I wrote it in the first place. Therefore I removed the earlier comment

Comment: Don't confuse letter $I$ with number $1$. For the example, $(p)$ is the ideal generated by a prime number $p\in\Bbb Z$. You must be familiar with the field $\Bbb Z/(p)$. For a more specific example, we have $(2+(5))^{-1}=(3+(5))$ in $\Bbb Z/(5)$ as $2\cdot 3=1+5$, while $2$ is not invertible in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Berci the part " $ab + I = 1 + I$ implies $ab = 1 + x$ for some $x \in I$" is what you wrote in the comment. This implication I don't understand

Comment: These are sets on both sides: $ab+I=\{ab+x:x\in I\}$ and $1+I=\{1+x:x\in I\}$. In particular, as $0\in I$, we have $ab\in ab+I$. So, that is also an element of $1+I$, meaning exactly that there's an $x\in I$ such that $ab=1+x$.

Comment: @Berci okay, so if I understand it correctly: if $a + I \in (R/I)^\times$, there MUS exist a $b + I \in (R/I)^\times$ so that $b$ IS the INVERSE of $a$ (like in your example $2^{-1} = 3 $ in $\Bbb Z /(5)$). And then we have $ab + I = 1 + I$. BUT, this doesn't have to imply that $a$ is invertible in $R$. Right?

Comment: Exactly, just as in the example, $2$ is not invertible in $\Bbb Z$.